# What is the meaning of "if (x) { … }" where x is an integer in C++?

Tags: c++, if-statement, syntax

I saw some c++ syntax that puzzled me

```
int x = 10;
if(x){ //this line confused me
//code 
}
else{
//code 
}
```

i don't understand how this is valid code, what does the `if(x)` do?

Comment: Nitpick: It's probably the semantics (using an `int` as an `if` condition) that are confusing you, rather than syntax (the text `if(x){`).

Answer (score 3):

An `int` converts implicitly to a `bool`. Any `int` that's non-zero evaluates to `true`. A zero integer converts to `false`. In your case, that line basically tests whether `x` is different from zero, and it is equivalent with

```
if(x != 0) ...
```